# Passing data with GET request instead of POST in flask app

Tags: python, flask

I am building flask app and I am trying to understand the routes , methods in flask documentation. I wrote a code which uses GET to submit the fields of a form :

```
@app.route('/',endpoint='buf')
def index():
    page = """
    <DOCTYPE! html>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="/hello" method="GET">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" ><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    """   
    return page


@app.route('/hello',endpoint="new",methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
        if request.method=='POST':
                return 'Hello %s' % (request.form['fname'])
        else:
                return 'Hello %s' % (request.form['fname'])
```

I get an error when I use 'GET' instead of 'POST' in my html form tag. Is there a way I can access the fields of the form using GET instead of POST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [relevant section at the quickstart guide](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#the-request-object)

To access parameters submitted in the URL (?key=value) you can use the args attribute:

```
searchword = request.args.get('key', '')
```

Comment: Hi , Can you tell me what is the data type of searchword? I used type(searchword) but i got an error that 2nd argument has to be removed. I do not understand what that error means

Comment: Use variable names and keys specific to your code.  Anyway the values to the keys in `request.args` should all be of type `str`.  I am not sure how you are calling `type` to cause that error.

Comment: Yes I am using key specific to my code. But I am sure that it is not a string , because when I try to convert it into integer(I need to pass it to a function which takes an integer) but I get an error that int() is not callable. Is searchword an object. How can I convert it to an integer. Any suggestions?

Comment: Whoops, if python2, it really is of type `unicode`, but it shouldn't stop you from converting between the two if your input is correct.  Will be continuing this on your [new thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650710/data-type-of-get-attributes/)