# Data type of GET attributes

Tags: python, flask

I was reading [a link]http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#the-request-object [a link]

If I have an html which consists of a form which has an element as:

```
<input type="text" id = 2 name="box"></input>
```

And I am using Flask app to get this dat in a GET request. from the documentation I came to know I can use

```
searchword = request.args.get('box', '')
```

I want to know what is the data type of searchwork , Is it an object. If it is an object is there a way I can convert it to an integer or string because I have a function which takes an integer and I want to pass the searchword there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just build a simple app and you can get your answer.

```
from flask import request, Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home():
    key = request.args.get('key', '')
    return 'key is `%s`, type(key) is %s\n' % (key, type(key))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Now run it.

```
$ wget -qO - 'http://localhost:5000/?key=value'
key is `value`, type(key) is <type 'unicode'>
```

If you want to convert that into an integer, you definitely want some kind of fallback.  So incorporating the other answer, you can do something like this

```
    return 'key is `%s`, type(key) is %s, key.isdigit() is %s\n' % (
        key, type(key), key.isdigit())
```

Trying this:

```
$ wget -qO - 'http://localhost:5000/?key=value'
key is `value`, type(key) is <type 'unicode'>, key.isdigit() is False
$ wget -qO - 'http://localhost:5000/?key=123'
key is `123`, type(key) is <type 'unicode'>, key.isdigit() is True
```

Then you can use the appropriate methods to handle your success and failure conditions, and use `int(value)` to cast `value` into an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [isdigit()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) check:

```
searchword = request.args.get('box', '')
if searchword.isdigit():
    my_function(int(searchword))
```

Or, just ["ask for forgiveness"](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html):

> **EAFP**
>
> Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. This common Python
>   coding style assumes the existence of valid keys or attributes and
>   catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast
>   style is characterized by the presence of many try and except
>   statements.

```
searchword = request.args.get('box', '')
try:
    my_function(int(searchword))
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: however isdigit() checks whether there is a number in the given str. But it seems like searchword is not even a str or I am not sure because i tried this example: I want to find the day based on the fields entered in a calendar . The form has three fields month, yr ,day and I need to select month -1 , day -1 , yr -2013 and I get all these attributes in a GET request and I use args.get to get all three values. Now when I pass them to a built in python function called calendar.weekday(yr,month,day) I get an Typeerror that an integer is required.